# Is there some case where awsRequestIds are not unique between lambda invocations

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

Trying to debug some lambda timeouts I noticed this - it seems like the awsRequestId is reused for multiple lambda invocations.  I was debugging a case where an invocation is timing out (a cron triggered lambda, one invocation exceeds the 15m limit).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A bit late, but yes, the `awsRequestId` could be the original request id which triggered the lambda.
For example, in a scenario where events are published into a SNS topic in batches of 10, a subscribed SQS will receive messages where the `awsRequestId` refers to the original publishing event (so group of 10 events will share the same `awsRequestId`).

Comment: It actually seems to be the case that lambda retries do reuse the request I'd.